# replace specific word in one line

Tags: shell, replace, grep

I'd love to grep **the exact words below** and replace them recursively from the current directory.

**CONDITIONS**

- `plan => service_plan`
- `Plan => ServicePlan`

Also if they lives in a middle of a sentence, it also has to be replaced.

- `abc_plan => abc_service_plan`
- `AbcPlan => AbcServicePlan`

Except those two words.

- `Stripe::Plan` x
- `stripe_plan` x

**I tried**

`grep -l 'plan' ./* | xargs sed -i.bak -e 's/plan/service_plan/g'`

But I'm not sure how I could exclude and include some more words.

It would be really appreciate if you add explanations for some option of the specific command!

Comment: What had you tried to do so far? Any direction you tried and failed? Write up your code

Comment: *some words* means some exact words. Can you show them?

Comment: yes some exact workds

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Actually the condition is already up there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search pattern requires using a negative lookbehind regex. Unfortunately standard shell utilities eg. `sed`, `awk` don't support lookbehind regex. I suggest using `perl` with `find` (for recursive search):

```
find . -type f -exec \
perl -i -pe 's/(?<!stripe_)plan/service_$&/g; s/(?<!Stripe::)Plan/Service$&/g' {} +
```

[Details on lookahead and lookbehind in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thanks! By the way what is lookbehind regex?

Comment: `(?<!stripe_)` part that asserts we cannot have `stripe_` text before `plan`.